# Vertically align elements in vuetify v-card component

Tags: vuetify.js, vertical-alignment, vcf-vcard

I am displaying 3 card components in a layout of 3 v-cols inside of a v-row like this (All 3 elements are currently v-card-text elements):

```
<v-row>
  <v-col>
    <v-card>{{elements}}</v-card>
  </v-col>

  <v-col>
    <v-card>{{elements}}</v-card>
  </v-col>

  <v-col>
    <v-card>{{elements}}</v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Since the content of element 2 consist of dynamically added text of various lengths they are not always of the same length and therefore height, resulting in a situation like this:

[image]

What I would like to achieve instead is that each element is placed in the same position across all three columns, according to the largest one, so that element 3 is always in the same position:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both `v-card` and `v-card-text` elements should be  styled with `height: 100%`.
Using the Vuetify css helper classes (`d-flex` & `flex-column`), set the `v-card-text` to `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. At this point you can use the `v-spacer` element to move the third element to the bottom.

Example:

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="4">
    <v-card class="full-height">
      <v-card-text class="full-height pa-2 d-flex flex-column">
        {{ element 1 }}
        {{ element 2 }}
        <v-spacer/>
        {{ element 3 }}
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="4">
    <v-card class="full-height">
      <v-card-text class="full-height pa-2 d-flex flex-column">
        {{ element 1 }}
        {{ element 2 }}
        <v-spacer/>
        {{ element 3 }}
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="4">
    <v-card class="full-height">
      <v-card-text class="full-height pa-2 d-flex flex-column">
        {{ element 1 }}
        {{ element 2 }}
        <v-spacer/>
        {{ element 3 }}
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>

<style scoped>
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

See [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-card-elements-placement-lvjnx?file=/src/components/CardTest.vue) for a working example

[image: Edit vuetify-card-elements-placement]

Comment: Thx, great and elegant solution.
For some reason it doesn't seem to work with my example. My current theory as to why involves my custom component in which the three elements are wrapped. So the structure is:

<v-row no-gutters align-content="space-between" justify="space-around">
    <v-col cols="4" v-for="choice in experiment.choices" :key="choice.name">
        <ChoiceComponent :choice="choice" />
    </v-col>
</v-row>

And inside ChoiceArchitecture, the structure is just as you described. Would that create an issue?

Comment: @masus04 Can you make a Sandbox?

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-card-elements-placement-hsytq?file=/src/components/InnerCard.vue ? For some reason I can't make it work properly right now, but it shows the idea.

Comment: @masus04 I am looking through your sandbox, and I do not see what is not working